# Не могу удалить данные с таблици

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть сервер на котором крутиться бд оралке 9i.
Администрирование осуществляю с удаленного пк через SQL Navigator 6.2.
Получилось так что переполнилась таблично пространство программа не пишет в базу таблицу,выдает ORA - 01653. Оказалось там 6 млн строк. Хотя не понимаю где стоит ограничение на количество записи.

Есть команда что бы увеличить табличное пространство, но там крутиться сложная база данных,рисковать не хочу.

Пытаюсь удалить данные с таблици командой truncate ,а мне пишет ORA-00054 ресурс занят  и получен с указанием  значением NOWAIT или истекло время ожидания.

```
SELECT
  O.OBJECT_NAME,
  S.SID,
  S.SERIAL#,
  P.SPID,
  S.PROGRAM,
  S.USERNAME,
  S.MACHINE,
  S.PORT,
  S.LOGON_TIME,
  SQ.SQL_FULLTEXT
FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT L,
     DBA_OBJECTS O,
     V$SESSION S,
     V$PROCESS P,
     V$SQL SQ
WHERE L.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
AND L.SESSION_ID = S.SID
AND S.PADDR = P.ADDR
AND S.SQL_ADDRESS = SQ.ADDRESS;
```

Сделал запрос,увидел что сессия активная, ну убил ее, проделываю манипуляции с truncate,снова ошибка ORA - 00054,если командой delete у попробовать удалить одну запись,просто виснет на ней, думал подожду. Пошел на обед, спустя 30 мин та же картина, тайм аута нету.

Дальше думал сделать через lock table, вижу что программа что писала в таблицу повисла, не может записать, но  delete,truncate не работают висят в процессе и все.

Можно конечно похоронить ее в базе, создать новую таблицу и в программе указать другой файл. Но меня это взбесило и хочется уже разобраться, что творится.

Как расширить табличное пространство?
Если в табличном пространстве кроме это таблици еще 30, как повлияет на это?

Comment: *переполнилась таблично пространство программа не пишет в базу таблицу,выдает ORA - 01653. Оказалось там 6 млн строк. Хотя не понимаю где стоит ограничение на количество записи.* Ограничение стоИт не на количество, а на размер. Если с дисковым пространством проблем нет, просто расширьте его, запросом типа `ALTER TABLESPACE system ADD DATAFILE 'system2' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 512K MAXSIZE 10000M`. Само собой подставьте свои параметры...

Comment: А каков ваш вопрос? Вы не можете расширить TS? Или какой?

Comment: Я дулам он очевиден и логичен. ALTER TABLESPACE system ADD DATAFILE 'system2' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 512K MAXSIZE 10000M что он делает.
Если у меня на таблично пространстве кроме это таблици крутятся другие,более серьезные, что будет с ними? для них тоже выделится место?

Comment: В табличном пространстве 30 таблиц, а забилась именно одна.

Comment: Если проблему с увеличением пространства не решить, другие таблицы в этом пространстве со временем тоже могут столкнуться с ошибкой. По поводу блокировки, возможно, ваш запрос не все блокирующие сессии видит (можно избавиться от соединения с `v$sql`), либо повторная блокировка успевает проскочить между прибитием сессии и попыткой `truncate`

Comment: Настройка базы была до меня, на других стоит job где чистит данные промежутком времени. Получилось воо так. lock table name table In exclusive  mode. truncate table name table. Но тут не понятно. В пятницу весел запрос , а в понедельник после выходных. Даже delete мог удалить одну строка. Видимо где-то весела сессия, мною не изведанная, и просто стоит длинный таймаут. Вопрос другой, как посмотреть сколько стоит времени до тайм аута?